# Ajax pagination in ZF2?

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2

I am new in `ZF2` but I did some projects in `ZF`. I didn't used any ajax pagination in `ZF`. But now I need ajax pagination in `ZF2`. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried google? http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/zend-framework-2-zendpaginator-paginate-your-data/

Comment: Yes I have already do this. I already implement zf2 pagination but need to know how to it with ajaxRequest. I do this using zf2 specified way and successful but when trying to do with ajaxRequest don't get any result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how I do it.

**FIRST STEP** (routes file):

I define a route for the pagination, diferent than the list one. I do this way to have the Controller functions as simple as possible.

```
'customers' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/customers',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'customers_controller',
            'action'     => 'list',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' =>array(
        //LIST
        'list' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/[:page]',
                'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'customers_controller',
                    'action'     => 'list',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        //PAGINATION
        'pager' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/pager[/:page]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'customers_controller',
                    'action'     => 'pager',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

**SECOND STEP** (module.config.php):

The reason I create the customers-content template is because when you do the AJAX call you just want the list itself, not the header. So my customers list is in this template.

It helps to keep clean the customers-list template, which has every HTML code except the list, which is retrieved by a call to this template.

```
'view_manager' => array( 
    'template_path_stack' => array( 
        __DIR__ . '/../view', 
    ),
    'template_map' => array(
        'customers-content' => __DIR__ . '/../view/customers/customers-content.phtml',
    ),
),
```

**THIRD STEP** (Controller class):

```
public function listAction() {
    (...)

    $view = new ViewModel;

    //SET THE VARIABLES NEEDED BY THE TEMPLATE VIEW
    $view->setVariables( $variables );
    //SET THE TEMPLATE VIEW
    $view->setTemplate( 'customers/list' );

    return $view;
}

public function pagerAction() {
    //POST DATA
    $data = get_object_vars( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );

    //GET DATA FROM THE DATABASE
    $customers = $this->customersMapper()->getCustomers( $data );

    //INITIALIZE THE PAGINATOR IN CASE THE DATABASE RETURNS ROWS
    if ( is_array( $customers ) ) {
        $paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator( new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter( $customers ) );
    } else {
        $paginator = $customers;
    }

    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage( 100 );

    //SET THE PAGE NUMBER FROM THE ROUTE
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber( 
        $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam( 'page', 1 )
    );

    //CREATE THE VIEW
    $view = new ViewModel;

    //SET THE VARIABLES NEEDED BY THE TEMPLATE VIEW
    $view->setVariables( 
        array(
            'customers' => $paginator,
        )
    );

    //SET THE TEMPLATE VIEW (THE TEMPLATE IS THE ONE DEFINED IN module.config.php)
    $view->setTemplate( 'customers-content' );

    $viewHTML = $this->serviceManager->get( 'viewrenderer' )->render( $view );

    //THAT'S THE INFORMATION THAT'LL BE RETURNED BACK TO THE CLIENT
    $result = array( 
        "success" => true,
        "HTML" => $viewHTML
    );

    //PREPARE THE RESPONSE WHITH THE ARRAY CONVERTED TO A JSON OBJECT
    $this->response->setContent( \Zend\Json\Json::encode( $result ) );

    //RETURN THE RESPONSE
    return $this->response;
}
```

**FOURTH STEP** (ticket-content.phtml):

```
<div id="customersList">
    <!-- HTML CODE THAT GENERATE LISTS' ROWS -->
    <?php
        //CALL TO THE PAGINATION TEMPLATE. WE PASS THE customers PAGINATOR CREATED IN THE CONTROLLER'S pagerAction()
        echo $this->paginationControl( $this->customers, 'Sliding', 'customers/customers-pagination.phtml' );
    ?>
    <!-- HTML CODE THAT CLOSES THE LIST -->
</div>
```

**FIFTH STEP** (customers-pagination.phtml):

```
<a id="pager_first" 
    href="<?php echo $this->url( 'customers/filter', array( 'page' => $this->first ) ); ?>">
        &lt;&lt; First
</a>
<a id="pager_previous" 
    href="<?php echo $this->url( 'customers/filter', array( 'page' => $this->previous-9 ) ); ?>">
        &lt;&lt; Previous
</a>
<?php foreach ( $this->pagesInRange as $page ): ?>
    <a id="<?= "pager_" . $page ?>">
        href="<?php echo $this->url( 'customers/filter', array( 'page' => $page ) ); ?>">
            <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<a id="pager_next" 
    href="<?php echo $this->url( 'customers/filter', array( 'page' => $this->next+9 ) ); ?>">
        &lt;&lt; Next
</a>
<a id="pager_last"
    href="<?php echo $this->url( 'customers/filter', array( 'page' => $this->last ) ); ?>">
        Last &gt;&gt;
</a>
```

**SIXTH STEP** (Javascript in template):

Place it wherever you want, customers-list.phtml, customers-content.phtml, customers-pagination.phtml.

```
$( function() {
    customers = new Customers();
    customers.initPagerElements( ["pager_first","pager_previous","pager_1-N","pager_next","pager_last"] );
} );
```

**SEVENTH STEP** (JavaScript File):

I use jQuery

```
//CREATE CUSTOMERS CLASS
Customers = function () {};

//INIT PAGER ELEMENTS FUNCTION
Customers.prototype.initPagerElements = function () {
    pagerElements = arguments[ 0 ];

    //ITERATE EACH PAGER ELEMENT
    $.each( pagerElements, $.proxy( function( index, elementId ) {
        var element = $( "#" + this.common.escapeSelector( elementId ) );

        var route = element.attr( "href" );

        item.click( { "route" : route }, this.clickHandler );
    }, this ) );
};

//CLICK HANDLER FUNCTION
Customers.prototype.clickHandler = function ( event ) {
    var route = event.data.route;

    //ASYNC CALL. IT MUST BE json TYPE
    $.post( 
        route, 
        null, 
        $.proxy( function( data ) {
            //IF THE CALL IS SUCCESS (REMMBER THE RESULT RETURNED FROM THE SERVER, 'success' AND 'HTML')
            if ( data.success ) {
                var container = $( "#customersList" );

                container.html( data.HTML );
            }
        }, this ),
        'json'
    );
}
```

Maybe there are typo errors, but it should work.